# Video in Beamer presentation: how to fill the slide

Tags: beamer, positioning, media9, movie15

I am trying to fill the white part of the slide in a beamer presentation through a video (which I embedded through movie15 but I can easily use medi9). 
Do you know how can I do? 
A sketch of the code that I used is below

```
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\vskip -x1.cm
\hskip -y1.cm
\includemovie[poster]{10.8cm}{7.5cm}{ff.mp4}
\end{frame}
```

In particular if I try to modify x1 y1 I am not able to find the correct place for the video. Then I am making wether exists an automatic way to do the described positioning? 
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post always full examples. `movie15` is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\dots

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node [anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south west) {%
    \includemedia[width=\pagewidth,height=\pageheight,...]{}{VPlayer.swf}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\dots

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But note, that the video player inevitably bubbles up to the top position to obscure all page content when activated.